# WCF настройка двусторонней связи

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Как на MSDN так и в других источниках информация разрезана на куски и я не могу склеить ее.

Итак, как в контексте WCF заставить сервер выполнить функцию и вернуть результат я разобрался, но не могу понять, как заставить сервер оповещать клиентов о каких либо изменениях. Например, на сервере есть каунтер и он между паузами увеличивается на 1. Как отправлять это изменение на клиент/ы?

Answer (score 3):

Оповещение клиентов реализуется только через [колбэки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx) (дуплексные операции). Тема эта достаточно обширная, рекомендую изучить классическую книгу по WCF - Juval Lowy, "Programming WCF Services", в частности, 5-ю главу.

Answer (score 3):

Как ответили ранее, для этих целей можно использовать коллбеки. Но в работе с коллбеками есть свои нюансы, и про них не стоит забывать. 
  Во-первых, клиент не должен закрывать соединение с сервисом, чтобы сервис мог дергать коллбеки этого клиента. 
  Во-вторых, стоит учитывать тот факт, что коллбек, который выполняется на клиенте может вызвать метод сервиса, и это может привести к блокировке при неправильной настройке клиента или сервиса.
  Для реализации через коллбеки необходимо сделать следующее:

1) Описать интерфейс (на стороне сервиса), который будет содержать сигнатуры коллбеков клиента.

```
public interface ICounterServiceClientCallback {
  [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
  void CounterChanged(int newValue);
}
```

2) В интерфейсе сервиса указать, что данный сервис может вызывать коллбеки.

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICounterServiceClientCallback))]
public interface ICounterService {
...
}
```

2) На стороне клиента реализовать этот интерфейс.

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class CounterServiceClientCallback : ICounterServiceClientCallback {
...
}
```

3) При подключении к сервису передавать объект данного класса конструктору прокси класса.

```
var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new CounterServiceClientCallback ());
_client = new CounterServiceClient(instanceContext);
```

4) На стороне сервиса создать объект коллбека и по необходимости вызывать методы этого объекта. При этом коллбек должен создаваться в методе, который вызывается клиентом.

```
var callback =  OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICounterServiceClientCallback>();
```

Все это хорошо описано в книге ["Создание служб WCF"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3822848/)

Comment: Добавлю, что для использования колбэков нужны дуплексные привязки (например, NetTcpBinding). Клиент должен наследовать от DuplexClientBase, либо нужно использовать DuplexChannelFactory. Также, если у вас установлен режим многопоточности Multiple или Reentrant, то колбэк не обязательно делать one-way. А вот в режиме Single - обязательно.